# Django makemessages command generate Permission denied

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization

When I run this command 
`python manage.py makemessages -l ru -a`
To build .po file I see such error

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './templates/base.html.py'
```

But I have not this template base.html.py I have only base.html in my template dir (without .py).
Help me please to understand what does it mean?

this is my settings.py

```
import os
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))[0]               
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "templates"), )   
DEBUG = True  
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG   
gettext = lambda s: s   
LANGUAGES = ( ('ru', gettext('Russian')), ('en', gettext('English')), )
MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'ru'  
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'   
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'  
USE_I18N = True  
USE_L10N = True
```

What I see in console

```
./manage.py makemessages -l ru -a processing 
language ru 
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './templates/base.html.py'
```

Comment: please, show the full trace

Comment: maybe you should write them in the post, not in a comment, nah?

Comment: The makemessages for javascript generates those ".html.py" files, and it seems like you don't have permission to create or write to the needed directory (./templates)